# Complex number $|z-w|$

Tags: complex-numbers

On an Argand diagram, sketch the locus representing complex numbers  satisfying $|z + i| = 1$ and the locus representing complex numbers w satisfying $\arg(w − 2) = \dfrac{3\pi}{4}$.
Find the least value
of $|z − w|$ for points on these loci.

I correctly sketch the Argand but how to find $|z-w|$, how to solve this, do i need to find the intersection between the 2 sketch...

Comment: just edited the pie

Comment: Do you know that $|z-w|$ is simply the geometric distance between two points in the diagram? If you have a sketch showing the two sets, it should be immediately obvious where the shortest distance between them is.

Comment: But how to calculate the distance ??

Comment: x @Arodio: You don't need to calculate it. It should be clearly visible on your sketch how far it is.

Comment: Are you assuming in $\;|z-w|\;$ that $\;z\;$ is on the circle $\;|z+i|=1\;$, and that $\;w\;$ is on the line $\;\arg(w-2)=\frac{3\pi}4\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, z is on the circle and w on the line.